# CGRIDVIEW TWO TABLES DATA DISPLAY IN YII

Tags: yii

i have 2 tables (STUDENT AND EMPLOYEE)

student(reg_no , s_name, dept, f_name) reg_no is primary key
employee(e_no,design,salary,reg_no)   reg_no is foreign key reference student(reg_no).

i want to display e_no,design  from employee 
and s_name,dept from student table.
so my complete cgridview would be

e_no, design,s_name,dept

my code for  employee/admin.php

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'employee-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->searchEmployees(),
//'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'e_no',
    'e_name',
    'design',
    'salary',
    'reg_no',
    array('name'=>'student.s_name',  'value'=>'$data->student->s_name'),   // student name
       'salary',  // employee.salary


    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),

),
));
?>
```

my code for model/employee.php for searchEmployees()

```
public function searchEmployees()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->alias = 'i';
$criteria->compare('e_no',$this->e_no);
    $criteria->compare('e_name',$this->e_name,true);
    $criteria->compare('design',$this->design,true);
    $criteria->compare('salary',$this->salary);
    $criteria->compare('reg_no',$this->reg_no);


$criteria->join= 'JOIN student d ON (i.reg_no=d.reg_no)';

return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'sort'=>array(
        'defaultOrder'=>'reg_no ASC',
    ),
));
}
```

BUT I FACE ERROR

Property "Employee.studentname" is not defined.

HOW TO SOLVE THE ERROR PLZ HELP.

THANKS

Comment: does this help: [relational database - displaying Cgridview in yii](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555410/displaying-cgridview-in-yii)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure the cgridview to display information for related records using [CActiveRecord->getRelated](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#getRelated-detail) in your customization of columns... it'd be as follows:

student(reg_no , s_name, dept, f_name) would be model `Student`.
employee(e_no,design,salary,reg_no) would be model `Employee`.

`Employee.e_no`, `Employee.design`, `Student.s_name` and `Student.dept` are your desired values so your columns array should be:

```
<?php 
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'student-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>Student::model()->search(),
        //'filter'=>$model,
        'columns'=>array(
            array(
                'header'=>Employee::model()->getAttributeLabel('e_no'), //column header
                'value'=>'$data->getRelated('employee')->e_no', //column name, php expression
                'type'=>'raw',
            ),
            array(
                'header'=>Employee::model()->getAttributeLabel(\'design\'), //column header
                'value'=>'$data->getRelated(\'employee\')->design', //column name, php expression
                'type'=>'raw',
            ),
            's_name',
            'dept',
        ),
    ));
?>
```

Notice how related record data is done in the 'value' specification of a custom column, and that the argument to getRelated() is the name of the relationship defined to the Employee model defined in the Student->relations() method. Also check [CGridView documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#columns-detail) on columns for more info on how this works.

**Update:** You can easily switch the approach of this CGridView instantiation  to use an `Employee` instead of a `Student` and still display the same info by changing the columns array.

**Update 2:** You can easily handle non existing relationships in the columns array:

```
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'header'=>Employee::model()->getAttributeLabel('e_no'), //column header
        'value'=>'($data->getRelated(\'employee\')=== null)?'No related employee registry':$data->getRelated('employee')->e_no', //column name, php expression
        'type'=>'raw',
    ),
    array(
        'header'=>Employee::model()->getAttributeLabel(\'design\'), //column header
        'value'=>'($data->getRelated(\'employee\')=== null)?'No related employee registry':$data->getRelated(\'employee\')->design', //column name, php expression
        'type'=>'raw',
    ),
    's_name',
    'dept',
),
```

With this tweaks in the `'value'` fields of our members in `'columns'` we display a small message whenever the model tries to access a related model. `getRelated()` returns the related record(s) or null if none is found. Maybe you have Students an equivalent Employee model, which might be the cause of the error. I hope the above helps you resolve it.

Comment: i used array same as u write but i face error:Student does not have relation "employee"

Comment: i used array same as u write but i face error:Student does not have relation "employee"..oh yes my relation name is student model is "employees" so i replace employee with employees...run it again but new error message :Trying to get property of non-object.C:\wamp\www\yii\framework\base\CComponent.php(607) : eval()'d code(1).

Comment: That error means that getRelated('employees') is failing to retrieve any model. You must ensure that it returns a model, or handle the null value.. Try my updated answer and tell me how it goes!

Comment: yes i try updated:2..same string "No related employee registry" in the columns fields. how can i ensure that student or employee relation is fail is get model.??thanks for your kind help.Plz reply

Comment: Relations for student.php 'employee' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Employee', 'reg_no'), and for employee.php 'Student' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Student', 'reg_no'),........plz also reply about filter and searching cgridview..thanks a lot

Comment: The problem here seems to be that whenever you save a new Student, you only save that Student and you have to separately save the related Employee. You could tweak your model using methods like [CActiveRecord::afterSave()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#afterSave-detail) in order to Save an Employee whenever you save a Student and Viceversa. If the relationship is way too tight, I'd consider fusing both tables into one in order to handle a single model.. But what you're trying to do now is coming thoroughly. Your relationships are correct, just make sure the rows exist.

Comment: but my actual problem is to how display two tables data in one cgrid view of employee/admin.php page.? and viceversa fiter and search. this is my actual problem..thanks

Comment: 'No related employee registry' means that the student exists, but it is not registered in the employee table, it is fixed as soon as you register the student in the employee table. You must check the documentation in [Specifying custom filtering for a related attribute in CGridView](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/28520-specifying-a-custom-filtering-for-a-relational-column-in-a-cgridview/) and the official [CGridView Documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView) in order to get yourself going.

Comment: i have already created primary and foreign key relationship..both tables are interrelated...

Comment: Correct, but in order for a Student to show it's **related Employee information** the Student Record or Instance must be existing. So if you have a Student with reg_no = 3, you MUST have an existing employee with reg_no = 3. That way the data can be found and displayed by Yii. So, registering a Student with reg_no = 4 DOES NOT automatically create an Employee with reg_no = 4, that's why that information is null, resulting in 'No related employee registry'...

Comment: o related employee registry'... So you must make sure you insert both your Student info AND the related Employee info with corresponding reg_no for it to be properly displayed..

Comment: Sir when i insert the data using phpMyadmin in both tables.Data is accurately inserted ,updated,deleted using constraints of primary key and foreign key. i have reg_no 1,2,3,4 in student table and reg_no,1,2,3,4,1,1,2,3 in employee table..so all data is well inserted at db level? so what the error may be in my code.?

Comment: Maybe the relation is not well formed in the `relations()` method in your model, can you show me both tables DDL and the `relations()` method in both of the models? or you can check the conformation of your `relations()` methods in [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#relations-detail).

Comment: Oh yes.its ok now. i have delete the db and recreate it .with this code its working well.@Snivs..Thanks for long and mature support.Thanks all members who contributed in this support.

Comment: ,i have implemented same code on my other project,but after trying again and again i failed to fulfill the task.can u help me? may i send u zipped code with db on ur email???plz let me know?thanks

Comment: Closer to the beginning of my answer, there should be a checkmark symbol in gray contour. Clicking it means you accept the answer by placing a green checkmark con it. This will also help other Visitors who see this question, by showing which answer was correct or fulfilled your needs better.